# Solving Fredholm Integral Equations of the first kind

Tags: integral-operators, kernels

I am looking to solve a Fredholm Integral Equation of 1st kind of the form:

$\int_{a}^b h(u-u')g(u')du' = f(u)$

where $h$ is a general function.

I know from the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem that all I need is the eigenvalues and the eigenfunctions of the Kernel - I can impose symmetry on the Kernel or even just consider the Gaussian Kernel.

Are there formulas for the eigenvalues and functions of the Gaussian Kernel? Are there other Kernels for which the eigenvalues and functions are tractable?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is $f = h*(g\cdot\chi_{[a,b]})$. So you can solve in terms of the Fourier transforms.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution